# Can I sort (order) list elements in python by by memory location?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, sorting, memory

This may actually be a nonsensical request, as I'll explain after I've asked it!

I have a list loaded in a script like this:

```
PROPERTIES = list(set().union(*[n.properties for n in NETWORKS]))  # random order
```

I use the set() function to avoid counting the same Property object twice (Property is a class I defined earlier, it's unrelated to python's own 'property' keyword).
Now, because sets are unordered, when I cast it into a list the resulting PROPERTIES may come out in a different order each time I load it.

When I access a object in the list, it will read something like "< ...object at 0x103098550>", where 0x103098550 is the internal memory of the object loaded.

My question is the following: Is there a way to then sort the list into ascending order of memory locations, such that the order of PROPERTIES will be the same each time I load it?

Note that the ordering of NETWORKS is always the same, there is no randomness there. The only possible randomness is when the set() function is called.

This might be a dumb question if the locations are dynamically generated with this line of code itself.

Edit: note. I'm not asking for the memory locations to be the same each time I load it (I know that's to do with my whole computer and may as well be random), but perhaps the *ordering* of memory of the objects n.properties is the same each time I load it. After all, when I build/load NETWORKS, I always load each network inside it in the same order, and presumably the memory locations assigned will go monotonically down (or up? I can't remember how heaps work).

Comment: As you have said in the question itself ("nonsensical request"), why do you need to do it? (this may be a XY problem)

Comment: Although I'm not sure if this is an XY problem, or if this is the correct original problem you're facing, but: [If you are trying to get "any consistent ordering", use hash.]

Comment: The memory locations are also random. There's no point sorting by them.

Comment: Thanks user202729! I don't actually know what an XY problem is though, I guess it's something to do with mis-referencing some object? At any rate I believe schwobaseggl has provided the answer I was looking for.

Comment: http://xyproblem.info/

Comment: And while schwobaseggl  exactly answered the "how to sort objects by memory location" question, it does actually not solves your real problem which is "how to deduplicate a list while preserving order". Typical XY problem indeed: you asked about the solution you've imagined instead of asking about your _real_ problem.

Comment: That's pretty patronising (using the word "n00b") and arrogant (dismissing someone's question on the grounds of misunderstanding the underlying real problem). The whole point of this platform is so that intermediate learners like me can seek expert help. It's true that I didn't quite ask the right question, but would you have liked to ask "how do I ask a question about this following stuff: ...?" as my topic question? I'm fairly sure it would get annoying if everyone did that. We can never be sure we're asking the perfect question, else we'd probably have quickly found the answer ourselves.

Comment: @GregoryFenn I don't know who your last comment targets, but FWIW: I'm not the author of the `xyproblem.info` page, I just linked to it so you could learn what's a XY problem is  (I dont personnaly use terms like "n00b" actually), and did in no way "dismiss" your question, just confirmed that is was a XY problem indeed - reformulating the question -, and posted  a tested, known working solution. If you find this more "patronizing" and "arrogant" than truly helpful and would rather accept a "solution" that exactly answers your question but will NOT work in a reliable way, well, your choice...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The memory location of any object is retrieved via the [`id`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#id) function. So you can do this:

```
sorted(PROPERTIES, key=id)
```

Comment: "Bureaucrat Conrad, you are technically correct - the best kind of correct. I hereby promote you to grade 37."

Comment: @gregory-fen: this is indeed the technically exact answer to your question - but as Rawing mentionned in a comment, memory location are in no way garanteed to be monotonic - they _might_ sometimes be and sometimes not -, so you'd better not rely on this.

Comment: Answers the question posed, but won't actually meet the OP's needs. OP, do not do this.

Comment: It's worth mentioning that the `id` function doesn't necessarily return the memory address of the object - that's a CPython implementation detail. In other words, sorting by memory location is something python-the-language doesn't even support.

Answer (score 4):

Relying on memory location - which is not garanteed to be monotonic (the Python runtime handles it's own memory pool and quite often reuses already allocated memory) - is certainly not going to work in a reliable way (it can *seem* to work sometimes - specially in a quick test script - but you can consider this as an accident).

A simpler solution (assuming your property objects are hashable) would be to use a `collections.OrderedDict` with dummy values:

```
from collections import OrderedDict
PROPERTIES = list(OrderedDict(n.properties, None) for n in NETWORKS))
```

This solution **is** garanteed to work.